# biojava import org.biojava not working

Tags: java, biojava

I am trying to use the example here:
http://www.biojava.org/wiki/BioJava%3aCookbook%3aSeqIO%3aReadGESBiojavax

However it isn't able to find the org.biojava imports I used.  I tried downloading and editting the POM.xml and adding it to the project but it didn't have any effect.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you are looking at is part of the legacy biojava release 1.8.X. Try with looking at the examples from the 3.X series...
http://www.biojava.org/wiki/BioJava:CookBook

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven? If this is the case you should be familiar to include this in your *own* `pom.xml` (not the downloaded one):

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
    <artifactId>biojava3-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other biojava jars as needed -->
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>biojava-maven-repo</id>
    <name>BioJava repository</name>
    <url>http://www.biojava.org/download/maven/</url>           
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

If you don't use Maven (which neither me nor the biojava-people recommend) you can download the required jar files here: http://www.biojava.org/download/maven/org/biojava/
But beware: You have to download and add all transitive dependencies (.jar files) used by biojava by yourself. I strongly recommend you give Maven a try in this case!

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the biojava.jar and include it in your classpath (you can maually download it from [here](http://biojava.org/wiki/BioJava%3aDownload_1.7.1)) -- note the .jar file might have some other required .jars that it needs

If you have a pom.xml, you can set up your project to be maven compatible and then run maven -- it will download all the required .jars and set up the classpath correctly (if the pom file is configured right)